# Troca de linha na matriz

Tags: python

Olá.
Estava programando em python e queria fazer a troca de linha(entre a segunda e terceira linha) de uma matriz utilizando o seguinte código. Porém eu queria saber porquer a variável `auxLinha` muda de valor quando modifico `b[inicio]`

```
def trocaLinhaB(b,inicio,final):
    listaAux = b[inicio]
    b[inicio] = b[final]
    b[final] = listaAux
```

A matriz original

```
0 2 3
0 -3 1
2 1 5
```

Porém o resultado foi

```
[[ 0.  2.  3.]
 [ 0. -3.  1.]
 [ 0. -3.  1.]]
```

e eu esperava o

```
[[ 0.  2.  3.]
 [ 2.  1.  5.]
 [ 0. -3.  1.]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que você esteja utilizando a biblioteca *numpy*, portanto, a variável `listaAux` armazena apenas uma visualização da matriz e não os dados (e por isso, ela "muda" de valor).

Quando você altera a matriz, altera também a visualização.

Uma solução possível para este problema é armazenar uma cópia dos dados na variável `listaAux` antes de fazer a substituição.

O código da função fica da seguinte forma:

```
def trocaLinhaB(b,inicio,final):
    listaAux = b[inicio].copy()  # <= aqui: cria uma cópia
    b[inicio] = b[final]
    b[final] = listaAux
```